# Obtener nombre mes pasado como parámetro a función en español

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-format

Estoy tratando de obtener el nombre del mes pasando como parámetro a mi función el numero del mes. Quiero que aparezca en castellano y no quiero usar la funcion deprecated **strftime** quiero actualizar mi código a funciones de php 8. He estado investigando bastante y he encontrado lo siguiente:

```
$formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(
                'es_ES',
                \IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
                \IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
                'Europe/Madrid'
            );
            
            return $formatter->format($mes);
```

pero no se como puedo pasar el nombre del mes a **IntlDateFormatter** para que aparezca solo Septiembre por ejemplo.

Espero me puedan orientar un poco. Uso php nativo nada de composer o librerías externas

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: muy buena pregunta hay te deje mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Dos puntos importantes:***

1. Obtener la fecha: para esto implemento un [formato relativo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) que soporta `DateTime` y que puede ser pasado como parametro a `IntlDateFormatter`.
2. Obtener el dato con el formato esperado: lo que pasa es que `IntlDateFormatter` tambien soporta formatos por ejemplo:

***Ejemplo:***

```php
<?php

$date = new DateTime('last day of last month');

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
                'es_ES',
                IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
                IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
                'Europe/Madrid',
                NULL,
                'MMMM'
            );
            
$datos = $formatter->format($date);

var_dump($datos);
```

Output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta la [documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.format.php), exactamente en el tercer ejemplo de la version OOP.

***Implementacion:***

```php
<?php

class DateManager
{
    public function getLastDayOfLastMonth(){
        return new DateTime('last day of last month');
    }
    
    public function getMonth($lang,$local,$format,$date){
        $formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
                $lang,
                IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
                IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
                $local,
                NULL,
                $format
            );
            
        return $formatter->format($date);
    }
    
}

$dateMAnager = new DateManager();

$month = $dateMAnager->getMonth(
    'es_ES', // puedo cambiar el idioma al quer me de la gana
    'Europe/Madrid', // me permite pasarle en base a que Region/ciudad quiero que saque la fecha
    'MMMM', // de esta forma puedo pasar cualquier otro formato
    $dateMAnager->getLastDayOfLastMonth() // de esta forma puedo pasar cualquier otra fecha
    );

var_dump($month);
```

Creando una clase que me permita jugar y trabajar dinamicamente con los datos.